# Angular combine and transform multiple http requests with forJoin Rxjs operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, operators, fork-join

I am combining multiple http requests with forkJoin rxjs operator.

```js
fetchUsers() {
    const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

    forkJoin(userIds.map(id => this.http.get(`${url}/${id}`))).subscribe(
      console.log
    );
  }
```

So, then I subscribe I get three objects, but I want to mutate that objects and get structure like this

```js
[{id:1, user: Object}, {id:2, user: Object}, {id:3, user:Object}];
```

I have tried using of operator but I get

```js
[{id:1, user: Observable}]
```

structure.
This is my stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uikppg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use rxjs [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator to transform data instead of using of operator inside forkJoin

```js
    fetchUsers() {
        const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    
        forkJoin(
          userIds.map(id => this.http.get(`${url}/${id}`).pipe((map(user=>({
            id,user
          })))))
        ).subscribe(console.log);
      }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5n5ew?file=src/app/app.component.ts)